# C# Finding peak few peak point in a List<double>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<double>` that contains many decimal numbers with values after the decimal point.
The list is used to draw a line chart of stock market and I want to find the peak point.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count-1; i++)
{
    if (list[i] > list[i-1] && list[i] < list[i+1])
    {
        peak.Add(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Please refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so to see what is a good question for SO

Comment: List<decimal> mylist = #whatever; decimal max = mylist.Max();

Comment: You want to get the maximum Number from the list?

Comment: i cannot be assigned as 0, so try to change int i = 1. If we understood what you wanted to do.

Comment: `list[i] > list[i-1]` this will take care that current value of list is greater than previous one. But `list[i] < list[i+1]` means you telling current value of list should be less then next. It will result a "Slop" in chart not a "peak" in chart. try updating second check in If with `list[i] > list[i+1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find peak point from your list. Like ***Lower - higher(peak value) - lower*** then you can try with this approach.

```
var nums = new List<double> {0.9, 1.8, 1.1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.3, 1.4};
for (int i = 1; i <= nums.Count-1; i++)
{
    if (nums[i] > nums[i-1] && nums[i] > nums[i+1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nums[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you're seeking Min and Max values in the list:

```
var list = new List<double>(){ 1.1d, 2.2d, 3.3d, 4.4d, 5.5d, 6.6d };
double maxValue = list.Max();
double minValue = list.Min();
```

Comment: Actually i want to find the peak point not max and min
I edited the question in above

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of indexes of where the current value was greater than the previous and the next value:

```
        var nums = new List<double> {1.1, 1.8, 1.4, 1.9, 1.3, 2.5};
        var peakPoints = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 1; i < nums.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //We start at index 1, because obviously the first value cannot be greater than the previous.
            //We also end at the second-to-last value because we can't check further.
            if(nums[i] > nums[i - 1] && nums[i] > nums[i + 1])
                peakPoints.Add(i);
        }
```

Comment: Generally, peak in line chart of stock market means, those points which are greater than previous and next values. there can be multiple peak points within one chart. However I'm not 100% sure if asker is asking for this or something else.

Comment: @Amit, If you check my answer, then you will see similar kind of code which supports what you are talking about.

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar of course, your current edit is exactly what i was taking about.